# Use docker secrets on a docker-machine

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-secrets

I'm having a problem trying to use docker secrets on a remote host that I created with docker-machine.

Below is my docker-compose.yml:

```bash
version: "3.5"

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_root_password
    secrets:
      - db_root_password

secrets:
  db_root_password:
    file: ./db_root_password.txt
```

This works well locally, I can run docker-compose up and access mysql container.

```bash
docker-compose up
```

The root password has well be applied.

I'm now trying to run the container on the remote host that I created using docker-machine.

I first created the machine using docker-machine create (in this case, on exoscale cloud)

```bash
docker-machine create --driver exoscale  ... MyMachine
```

Then I tried to deploy the host using:

```
eval $(docker-machine env MyMachine)
docker-compose up
```

However, when I try to run on the remote host, I got the following error:

```bash
ERROR: for mysql  Cannot create container for service mysql: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /Users/user/path/to/db_root_password.txt
```

So it's still trying to load the secret with the path of the local file on my local machine. How can I use this secret on the remote host?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: I think you will have an easier path if you use swarm and `docker stack deploy` rather than `docker-compose up`. Everywhere I see that discusses secrets in compose, is in swarm context. Then, you create the secret just like you create networks, and they are a part of the swarm and accessible to containers you allow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looks like tour docker-machine can't find `./db_root_password.txt`

Can you try to create the file `db_root_password.txt` inside the docker-machine in the same path?

Comment: Can you explain about your answer bit more?, where and how to create this file inside docker-machine?

Comment: You can create the .txt using a volume: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/